# Transparent background for live motion capture and performance

Tags: transparency, motion-capture

All the questions on this subject relate to rendering, so I don't think this is a duplicate.
I'm trying to display a character for motion capture on a completely transparent background.  It is NOT for rendering purposes.  It is for LIVE motion capture and performance.
In other words, I need no plane, no world, just emptiness!
Can anyone explain how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest method for me would be using green background in Blender and Chroma key filter in OBS Studio:

1. In Blender, set Display -> Render Only and tick World Background

   [image]
2. Set World Background Color to green

   [image]
3. Hide all UI so it looks like this, you can go fullscreen by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>
   [image]
4. In OBS Studio, add corresponding Display or Window to Sources list, then right click on the scene preview -> Filters -> Chroma Key, make sure the green is selected
   [image]
5. The resulted scene you can live stream
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jan.  I'm not sure about using OBS studio - do I need to add another application?  I'm already running too many!  I was hoping there was a simpler way to do this just within Blender.  I'm using Syphoner to send it to another syphon client at the moment.

Comment: Blender is not a broadcasting application so you definitely need another app to grab the screen so you can broadcast it as a "realtime video". Then the only way how to achieve transparency is using the Chroma key (green screen) method. Unfortunately your Syphoner application doesn't offer this feature so you need OBS or another app that supports it.
But maybe someone will find another solution I am not aware of.

Comment: OK, I understand.  Thanks for taking the time to share all the screenshots and giving so much detail, much appreciated!